# What happens after I run rebuild project in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

The document http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/rebuilding-project.html?search=reb only tells me how to rebuild a project.

I don't know what does it mean to rebuild a project (`Menu --> Build --> Rebuild Project`), will it clean all edit cache?  I find the size of the project reduced after I run rebuild project?

What does it mean to clear a project in Android Studio?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Android Studio, almost every voice in the build menu is mapped to a (possibly more than one) gradle action, where Gradle is the official build system for android. In particular, when you clean the project you are deleting some files from the build folder inside your app module, and when you select rebuild that's the equivalent of doing a gradle clean and build.
For more information on the topic I suggest this course on Udacity, which you can view for free. It teaches you gradle and how it integrates with android studio.

https://www.udacity.com/course/gradle-for-android-and-java--ud867

Comment: To flower_green:  Colud you give me a link about rebuild project? I can't find it at https://www.udacity.com/course/gradle-for-android-and-java--ud867 .Thanks!

Comment: I could not find a link specifically about rebuild project, but as it says in the course, I think your best bet is to click rebuild project and see which gradle tasks are executed in the gradle console window of android studio. When you click rebuild the following three tasks are executed: [clean, :app:compileDebugSources, :app:compileDebugAndroidTestSources], where the name of the last two changes according to the release type and the current flavor. Here you can find some more info on the tasks executed: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Tasks

Answer (score 0):

Android App is a Gradle project that uses `com.android.application` plugin. When you click rebuild button, clean button, or run button. It will run a series of command. Note that not all command is a Gradle Task. For example, run and debug button is going to run `adb` behind the scene.

In `Rebuild` button you're running multiple Gradle tasks. You can see it in the bottom right section of Android Studio.

[image: Gradle Console Tab]

In this case, Android Studio will run the following Gradle tasks:
`clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:compileDebugSources, :app:compileDebugUnitTestSources, :app:compileDebugAndroidTestSources`

What you see before colon (:) is the module name. `app:generateDebugSource` is going to run `generateDebugSource` task on `app` module.

But what happened if you have multiple modules?

[image: Multiple Module]

Apparently, Android Studio will run those task on each module.

```
Executing tasks: [clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:compileDebugSources, :app:compileDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:compileDebugUnitTestSources, :myandroidlib:generateDebugSources, :myandroidlib:mockableAndroidJar, :myandroidlib:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :myandroidlib:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :myandroidlib:compileDebugSources, :myandroidlib:compileDebugUnitTestSources, :myandroidlib:compileDebugAndroidTestSources]
```

> will it clean all edit cache? I find the size of the project reduced
>   after I run rebuild project ?

It will clean files in `build` folder. Usually, this is not included in a project (added in `.gitignore`). A `build` folder will have your final `apk`, an `R` files, a report file (like lint / JUnit test report), and generated classes (from Dagger / Retrofit). That's why it will reduce the size of your project.

> BTW, what mean does it to clear project in Android studio?

If what you mean by `clear project` is `clean project`.

[image: Clean project]

Android Studio will run these following tasks, which essentially deletes `build` folder.

`Executing tasks: [clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :myandroidlib:generateDebugSources, :myandroidlib:mockableAndroidJar, :myandroidlib:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :myandroidlib:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]`