# How to run 'rebuild project' from the command line

Tags: android, windows, android-studio, gradle, msbuild

#### Some Context:

I am working on a Continuous Integration pipeline with MSBuild for a large project that includes an Android application.  This application includes some automatically generated files that need to be integrated into the project regularly.  This is usually accomplished by manually copying them over and selecting Build->rebuild project in android studio.

This step is necessary since the project also makes use of [AndroidAnnotations](http://androidannotations.org/), which generates classes at compile time.

#### The Problem:

I haven't found any documentation for what is run when you select 'rebuild project' in android studio.

#### What I Have Tried:

[How to Rebuild and Run android project from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41480120/how-to-rebuild-and-run-android-project-from-command-line)

as well as:

[What is happened after I run rebuild project in Android studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30662446/what-is-happened-after-i-run-rebuild-project-in-android-studio)

But the doccumentation [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline.html) doesn't talk about the rebuild command, and a 6 week udacity course isn't a helpful resource either.

When I hit 'rebuild project' the Android Studio event log reads:

> Executing tasks: [clean, :app:generateDevelopmentDebugSources, :app:generateDevelopmentDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:prepareDevelopmentDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:compileDevelopmentDebugSources, :app:compileDevelopmentDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:compileDevelopmentDebugUnitTestSources]

Which I have run in the command line as follows:

> gradlew.bat clean :app:generateDevelopmentDebugSources :app:generateDevelopmentDebugAndroidTestSources :app:prepareDevelopmentDebugUnitTestDependencies :app:mockableAndroidJar :app:compileDevelopmentDebugSources :app:compileDevelopmentDebugAndroidTestSources :app:compileDevelopmentDebugUnitTestSources

The command executes, but the build finishes with several hundred errors, which also occur when you try to compile or clean without first running rebuild.  Obviously this command is incomplete.

When I look at the Gradle Console in Android Studio I see a couple of dozen targets that are run, but I'm hesitant to copy-paste those, as I have no idea what small changes to the project will necessitate different targets to be run.

I've narrowed down my issue to the `:app:compileDevelopmentDebugUnitTestJavaWithJavac` target.  This target requires one of the other targets listed in the Gradle Console, but I don't know which one.

Those targets have to be coming from somewhere, but where?

#### tl;dr:

How can I do all the things that Android Studio does when I run 'rebuild project' from the command line?

Comment: usually from terminal you would run
`./gradlew clean build assemble `
now last one can be anything else like: assembleDebug

try

Comment: @dario.budmir I've played with it and tried  your solution, there's still a target missing somewhere.  I think the key question is "Where does Android Studio get all these targets from?"

Comment: can you post build log with --stacktrace --debug

Comment: you could run: ./gradlew clean build assemble  --stacktrace --debug

Comment: so the output of the stacktrace is 14 MB. I'll try and post the relevant sections

Comment: upload to pastebin or smilar hosting sites

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135695/discussion-between-sam-borick-and-dario-budimir).

Comment: As with many posts this age, I since left my job related to this project, and have migrated to a different tech stack altogether.  Any answers would still be appreciated for others having this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Please open `build` view in Android Studio, when you select from menu: `Build -> Rebuild Project` on the top in `build` view you will see which tasks were triggered by Android Studio: `Executing tasks: [clean, :assembleDebug] in project ...`

[image]

And now you can try to do this from command line:

`./gradlew clean assembleRelease`

Comment: The question is 'How to run 'rebuild project' from the command line'.  This answer does not include the command line.

Comment: @SamBorick In the end of my answer you can find:
`./gradlew clean assembleRelease`

Answer (score 0):

**Rebuild** and **build** are the same thing. You can list all the gradle tasks by running a command `gradle task --list` or    `gradle -q :tasks --all`   . There you can see different types of gradle tasks. For example, install tasks, build tasks, assemble tasks, publishing tasks, verification tasks, build setup tasks, clean tasks, android task, or your own custom named tasks etc. Run on the build tasks from your module (e.g., `MyModule:build`) like this `gradle MyModule:build` (or `./gradlew MyModule:build` if you wanna use inside gradle wrapper)

**Note**: you can see your runnable/buildable module from **Run Configurations** also.